# How to use GPS to remind me to shop for something?

Tags: applications

In my town I have to do a lot of shopping in a lot of different places. Sometimes I find myself wanting to remember to buy some things when I'm passing by a certain place.

Is there some easy and free way to achieve this with an Android phone?

Comment: I have often been wanting an application like that. But I would primarily want location to be decided based on WiFi SSID rather than GPS coordinates, since most of the time I have WiFi enabled and GPS disabled. I also find it easier to remember the SSID than GPS coordinates.

Comment: @kasperd Android will use whatever location services you have enabled.  I don't think any of the answers are restricted to GPS.

Comment: Lots of choices here for [Location based reminders](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert#group_485) :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep) is a free application that allows you to take notes, and create location or temporal reminders that will trigger the notes.

Comment: Google Inbox also has this feature built-in.

Comment: I have used Keep with good results when I gave it a precise address, but once I set a location reminder "When I'm at CityName", and I didn't get the notification until several weeks later, when I just HAPPENED to be very near the center of the city.  I absolutely LOVE Google Keep, but this was disappointing.  :-\  Maybe they have improved it in the mean time, but I'm still a bit leery of trusting location reminders myself.

Comment: Google Now also has this feature (location-based reminders)

Answer (score 17):

You can do this via Google Now or even via browser. Just say "Remind me to buy ice cream the next time I am at Fry's" and the next time you're at Fry's, it will remind you to get ice cream.

Most of the Google Now features are available via any browser as well. Just search Google for that same statement and it will offer to "Set a reminder" above real results.

Real handy and should be available on any phone running Jelly Bean (4.1) or higher, so likely most phones released in the last 3 years or so.

Comment: This is the most straightforward and convenient way, but I have found that it's not always accurate - sometimes I haven't been reminded until after I had left.

Comment: @StephenAngelico Yeah, I've tried it a few times over the last day and I've had the same issue. It's a bit disappointing

Answer (score 6):

[Shifu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thesignals) is a free android application available on Google Play Store that lets you create reminders in most flexible ways. Apart from location based reminders that you require, you can also set reminders on Calls, Wi-Fi connectivity etc. 
It has other interesting features too, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) was designed for this type of thing, but I'm not sure I'd call it simple.

I use it to prevent the phone ringing (auto hangup) when maps and USB power is on the phone... when I'm driving.

Comment: If possible, explain the steps to fulfill OP's question. You don't need to describe in many words, just a simple "Tap <this>, select <location>" should be enough.